# "Прочитанную книгу" или "читаемую книгу"?

Tags: глаголы

I open a read book.

Здесь рэд это третья форма глагола, то есть она означает и прочитанный и читаемый одновременно!
Тогда как правильно перевести:

Я открыл прочитанную книгу.
или
Я открыл читаемую книгу. (недочитанную)

Comment: I think you should ask this question at https://ell.stackexchange.com/, not here.

Comment: скорей всего **прочитанную**, **читаемая** скорей всего будет выражено как **being read**, но в то же время значение причастия по-моему амбивалентно и оно может пониматься по-разному под влиянием контекста

Comment: @Ivan Olshansky Там язык общения - английский, поэтому вряд ли ответят.

Comment: Исходное предложение не имеет ясного смысла. Если в русском времена и законченность действия (совершенный вид) _встраиваются_ внутрь глагола или причастия, то в английском модификация глаголов и причастий во многих случаях требует _внешних_ элементов. Я открыл **читаемую** (всеми) книгу. I opened a _widely read_ book. Я открыл **прочитанную** (мною) книгу.  I opened a book I had _already read_.

Comment: Спасибо! А как сказать Я открыл читаемую (мною) книгу?

Comment: Да, когда язык общения английский по мне так это плохо, а не хорошо. 
Во-первых надо понять почему у русского человека возникает непонимание, для этого желательно чтобы преподаватель был "на его стороне" то есть знал русский язык как родной. Во-вторых, на русском можно понятнее объяснить. Так что ну их всех этих носителей языка и прочих преподавателей кто весь урок балакает на английском...

Comment: (Я открыл читаемую мной книгу) Один из возможных вариантов: I opened the book _currently read_ by me.

Comment: @user190920, вы о каком языке спрашиваете? "Я открыл читаемую книгу" - так и будет. Ну или "Я открыл книгу, которую читал". Что касается английского языка общения, то из его наличия следует, что на этом сайте вопросы задают иностранцы, изучающие русский язык. Если же вопрос задается по-русски, то и отвечают, как правило, на русском языке. English stack exchange не тут, тут не English stack exchange.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! This site is a question and answer site about Russian language. It seems that you are an English learner who is asking about the meaning of an English phrase, am I right? If that's the case, the best place on the Stack Exchange network to ask this kind of questions would be https://ell.stackexchange.com/, the question and answer site for English language learners. You would have to translate your question into English to ask it there.

Comment: However, if you know the meaning of the English phrase and are looking for a better way to translate it to Russian, this is the right place. Translating phrases out of context is very tricky, so as the others have already mentioned, you would receive better answers if you provided some context for this phrase, ideally the excerpt from the text where you saw it.

Comment: Finally I'd like to mention that although this site is about Russian language and many its users, myself included, are fluent in Russian and/or are native Russian speakers, we want people who are not fluent in Russian to feel at home and understand what is going on here. We do allow and welcome questions and answers in Russian, however I and many others prefer to communicate in English to encourage participation from the users who would not otherwise be comfortable to write in a language they could barely use. We have a sister site, rus.stackexchange.com, which is completely in Russian.

Comment: Thank you again and welcome to Russian.SE!

Comment: на мой взгляд наиболее эффективный способ изучения иностранного языка - это его изучение на нём же, т.е. с погружением, хотя это и сложновато на первых порах, во всяком случае именно об этом свидетельствует мой собственный опыт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно - переводить, пользуясь контекстом. Здесь слишком мало информации из оригинала, чтобы сделать перевод правильно.

Если же это упражнение, где надо просто перевести фразы на русский, то напишите два варианта и покажите вашему учителю, что вы знаете оба.

Я не понимаю, почему ответы упорно переносятся в комментарии, тогда как сообщения не по теме не модерируются.